# Get value from property and serialize it

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, uwp

I writing app for UWP.

I have this code

```
private List<RootObject> ordersList;

    public List<RootObject> OrdersList
    {
        get { return ordersList; }
        set
        {
            ordersList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    private RootObject ordersChange;

    public RootObject OrdersChange
    {
        get { return ordersChange; }
        set
        {
            ordersChange = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

When I click button value write to `ordersChange` and `set` to value.

I need to take value, serialize and send via post request.

```
  using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://api.simplegames.com.ua");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("utf-8"));

            string endpoint = @"/post_from_local.php";

            try
            {
                HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(*****), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(endpoint, content);
```

Where `***` is value. How I can do this?

Thank's for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to post OrdersChange you can do like this.

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(viewModelInstance.OrdersChange);
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response  = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content);
```

Comment: I want to post OrdersChange.

Comment: The name 'ordersChangeInstance' does not exist in the current. Have this error.

Comment: I corrected you can use viewModelInstance.OrdersChange . viewModelInstance is variable Name if you're using httpclient in viewmodel you can use this.OrdersChange

Comment: like this? `HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.OrdersChange), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");`

Comment: where is your viewModel? & where is public async void ElementPost() method?Can you post the whole  code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128161/discussion-between-eugene-and-haksu).